# GWT: How to send one variable from client side code to server side code

Tags: gwt, client-server

Thanks for helping me,i can not explain everything but simply I am writing as follows

Say,inside the client file (which implements EntryPoint), a variable DELAY=200,has its initial value but after some time client needs to send this value to the server side code where in server side (DataServiceImpl.Java) file the initial value was sDelay=500, then it will be changed to 500 to 200(client variable). How to do this ??How to pass these values ?

Thanks for your time.

Google Web toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GWT developer guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide.html) contains an entry on [client-server communication](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html). There are also a fair number of third-party libraries that offer a variety of feature-sets.